# In React native Keyboard shows on the Modal in IOS only ,Working fine in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using react-native-paper Modal.

I used KeyboardAvoidingView but its not working. It working fine in android ,But it's not working in IOS.
I have specify behaviour as padding, position, height of KeyboardAvoidingView but it doesn't work
Please give any solution.

Screenshot on Android [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UETKh.jpg

Screenshot on IOS[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDib.png

My code is as below:

```
<Modal
    contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 20, borderRadius: 10, marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30 }}
    animationType="fade"
    visible={this.state.dialogVisible}
>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' enabled>
        <Text style={styles.descDialogInqueryFor}> Inquire for </Text>
        <TextInput
            autoFocus={true}
            maxLength={50}
            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
            style={styles.inpuTextDialog}
            placeholder='Name'
            placeholderTextColor='#C7C7CD'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ name: text })}
        ></TextInput>
        <TextInput

            autoCompleteType={'email'}
            maxLength={40}
            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
            style={styles.inpuTextDialog}
            placeholder='Email'
            placeholderTextColor='#C7C7CD'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.validateEmail(text)}
        ></TextInput>
        <Text style={[styles.errorText, { display: this.state.displayEmailError }]}>Invalid email address</Text>
        <TextInput

            autoCompleteType={'email'}
            maxLength={40}
            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
            style={styles.inpuTextDialog}
            placeholder='Email'
            placeholderTextColor='#C7C7CD'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.validateEmail(text)}
        ></TextInput>

        <Text style={[styles.errorText, { display: this.state.displayPhoneError }]}>Invalid phone number</Text>
        <TextInput
            maxLength={30}
            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
            style={styles.inpuTextDialog}
            placeholder='Subject'
            placeholderTextColor='#C7C7CD'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ subject: text })}
        ></TextInput>
        <TextInput
            blurOnSubmit={true}
            multiline={true}
            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
            style={styles.messageInpuText}
            placeholder='Message'
            placeholderTextColor='#C7C7CD'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ message: text })}
        ></TextInput>

        <Button style={styles.sendButtonDialog} onPress={() => this.sendInquire()}>
            <Text style={styles.sendButtonText}>Send</Text>
        </Button>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add  KeyboardSpacer in the Modal

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you don't want any issue about keyboard you need using scrollview and observer keyboard show/hide for animal fix layout. Custom yourself.

I have get this issue too and because I support many version ios so using KeyboardAvoidingView can not fix all of them and sometime get some hidden issue just appear when you have many user using special version.
Android auto scroll content when layout change so you no need to do anything to fix layout when keyboard show. If you check KeyboardAvoidingView for ios maybe it effects to android. So observer keyboard show and custom yourself will be best that is mine sugess.

PS I remember KeyboardAvoidingView have contentOffSet attribute to fix animation scroll when keyboard change state. But I very confused how to using it fixable for all version ios and after many trying time I custom myself. Hope my experience can help you see the right way in your case